# I am trying to use a method which is in different class but it generates an error

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is the main class in which I want to use the `insertData()` method. This method is from a different class `InsertOperation`, both of the classes are in the same package but still I can't use the method.
I am new to java and I am still struggling to grasp it all.

```
package crudoperations;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.*;

public class CRUDOperations {
    /*
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE employee "
                                    + "(" + "user_id INT(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + 
                                        "first_name VARCHAR(100)," +
                                        "last_name VARCHAR(100)," +
                                        "contact_number INT(10)," +
                                        "email_id VARCHAR(100))";
*/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = nulll;
        try{
            con = // File enter code here Connection.getConnection();
            InsertOperation iop = InsertOperation(); //Showing error in this line
            iop.insertData();
            
            //System.out.println("Connected");
            //stmt = con.prepareStatement(CREATE_TABLE);
            //stmt.executeUpdate();
            
            //System.out.println("Table Created");
            
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.print(e);
        }
        finally{
            if(con != null){
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Here is the code for InsertOperation class:

```
package crudoperations;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsertOperation {
    public void insertData() throws SQLException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the First Name: ");
        String user_firstname = sc.next();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Last Name: ");
        String user_lastname = sc.next();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Contact Number: ");
        String user_contact = sc.next();
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Email ID: ");
        String user_email = sc.next();
        
        Connection con = null;
        con = FileConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO employees "
             + " (user_id, first_name, last_name, contact_number, email_id)"
             + " VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        
        pst.setString(2, user_firstname);
        pst.setString(3, user_lastname);
        pst.setString(4, user_contact);
        pst.setString(5, user_email);
        
        int i = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(i != 0){
            System.out.print("success");       
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("error");
        }     
    }
}
```

Here is the error :

```
error: cannot find symbol
            InsertOperation iop = InsertOperation();
  symbol:   method InsertOperation()
  location: class CRUDOperations
```

Comment: Presumably you want to create an instance of the class, which you do with a constructor call: `InsertOperation iop = new InsertOperation();` - note the `new` part which your code is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a instance if you want to access the instance method.

```
InsertOperation iop = new InsertOperation();
```

I think you may forget the new key word here.

Else you may use static key word when declaring the insertData() method like below.

```
public static void insertData() throws SQLException
```

and then just access that method calling just method name.

```
Ex: insertData();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was so silly of me to forget this....

Answer (score 0):

Missing "new" keyword for object creation.

````
```
   InsertOperation iop = InsertOperation(); //Showing error in this line
```
````

Should be

```java
InsertOperation iop = new InsertOperation();
```